# Mixed values of arguments, when I call pointer member function

Tags: c++, function, pointers, qt-creator

I have called a pointer of member function from another class. This function has 2 arguments.
It is working... But in this member function, in the debugger,  I see that values of arguments were swapped (mixed). I see the correct values but not in correct variables(arguments). May be it is BUG...
Qt Creator c++

```
void SmartCTL::OnReadBufferA(int shm_id, int length); //declaration
 hookedIDs[HOOKIDPOINTERS::READBUFFERA] = (void *)&SmartCTL::OnReadBufferA; // Save pointer of function
memcpy(hookedIDs[smartCTL.shellID],smartCTL.hookedIDs,8*sizeof(void *));// copy pointers
void (*pf)(int,int )= (void(*)( int,int ))hookedIDs[i][HOOKIDPOINTERS::READBUFFERA];// set pointer 
 pf(shells[i]->readBuff.shm_id,shells[i]->readBuff.length); // call hear
```

In result I get value *hells[i]->readBuff.shm_id* in *length* and value *shells[i]->readBuff.length* in *shm_id*

Comment: Why are you performing so many casts? Especially C-style casts? This looks really suspicious and I wouldn't be surprised if you're invoking *undefined behavior* somewhere in there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't a bug.  What you have is undefined be behavior.  A member function is not the same as a regular function.  There is a `this` in the member function and the way it gets that is through an implicit function parameter of the class type.  So

```
void SmartCTL::OnReadBufferA(int shm_id, int length)
```

is really something like

```
void SmartCTL::OnReadBufferA(SmartCTL& this_ref, int shm_id, int length)
```

And this is why you can't cast a pointer to a member function to a pointer to a regular function.

If you need to have both member functions and regular functions in your "array" then you are going to need a [`std::function`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function?).  It uses type erasure to allow you to to store different types of function objects that have the same interface.  For example you could have something like

```
std::vector<std::function<void(int, int)>> functions;
functions.push_back(some_regular_function);
functions.push_back([](int shm_id, int length){ SmartCTL s; return s(shm_id, length); });
```

Another option is to make the member function a static function.  A static function does not have a instance of the class bound to it so you can treat it as a regular function.